# In a particular page the key board was take too much of time to load any solution

Tags: android

I have a activity screen contains almost 100 views (Edit text .labels,spinner) ,in that screen  keyboard takes too much of time to load. Thanks in Advance

Comment: device ram capacity is less maybe ??? :P

Comment: i am using samsung tab for test

Answer (score 2):

Layout having more than 80 views is bad for performance. Try decreasing number of views. If you can't, you can try to divide your activity in two.

You can also use HiearchyViewer tool in android-sdk/tools/ to see where the problem is.

Here is the link describing how to use it: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response i have split my views into  different layouts and the visibility of all layout was gone( except the one which have Edittext)  but still it take more time to hide the keyboard

Comment: Can't you place some of those views in a seperate activity? Then you can start that activity with a next button maybe?